# Django 1.7 Configure App Directory Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to load app specific templates in my Django 1.7 project. Here is my directory structure:

```
ProjectX
   - manage.py
   - ProjectX
      - settings.py
      - urls.py
   - App1
      - urls.py
      - Templates
        - App1
           - something1.html
   - App2
      - urls.py
      - Templates
        - App2
           - something2.html
```

Now i have configured the following into my ProjectX/ProjectX/settings.py:

```
  TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     TEMPLATE_PATH,
  )
```

When I do:

```
  render_to_response("app1/somthing1.html",.....)
```

I go to the PATH  ProjectX/Templates/App1/something1.html

Whereas I would want something like ProjectX/App1/Templates/App1/something1.html

Any idea how I can make this happen without changing the render_To_response statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `TEMPLATE_PATH` in your settings and change `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'App1/templates').replace('\\', '/'),
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'App2/templates').replace('\\', '/')
)
```